# javac compiling returns missing package

Tags: java, cmd, javac

During compiling my project with javac in command line promp it returns many errors and the first one is : package javax.jms does not exists.

Even though there are no problems in Eclipse with the import statment or anything.

The project is located in :

D:/Workspace/MessageQueingChat

I run from  D:/Workspace/MessageQueingChat:

javac src/model/Chat.java

Thanks!

Comment: Import packages related jars not exist in classpath. so it throws such errors. so set `classpath`.

Comment: Can you give me an example..